# If $x_1, x_2,...,x_{10}$ are such that $\sum_{i=1}^{10} \sin^2(x_i) = 1$, prove that $3 \sum_{i=1}^{10} \sin(x_i) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{10} \cos(x_i)$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, complex-numbers

> Take $x_1, x_2,...,x_{10}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{10} \sin^2(x_i) = 1$ with $x_1, x_2,...,x_{10}$ on $\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$, prove that $3 \sum_{i=1}^{10} \sin(x_i) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{10} \cos(x_i)$.

I tried to do this:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{10} \sin^2(x_i) = \frac{
n-\sum_{i=1}^{10} \cos(2 x_i)}{2} = 1 \rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^{10} \cos(2x_i) = 8$$
So i said $\sum_{i=1}^{10} \cos(2x_i) = A$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{10} \sin(2x_i) = B$. Therefore: $$A + Bi = \sum_{i=1}^{10} \operatorname{cis}(2x_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{10} \operatorname{cis}^2(x_i)$$
But I make no idea about how I will get the inequality. Anybody can help me?

Comment: Is "sen" intended to be the sine function, $\sin$?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I'm Brazilian, and here we use sine function as "sen".

Comment: OK, no problem.

Comment: There is an error in your first calculation:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \sin^2(x_i) = \frac{n}{2} \left(1-\sum_{i=1}^n \cos(2 x_i)\right)
$$
should be
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \sin^2(x_i) = \frac{1}{2} \left(n-\sum_{i=1}^n \cos(2 x_i)\right)
$$

Comment: My bad, but I am still having the same problem :(

Comment: Please see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180885/prove-frac-cosx-1-cosx-2-cdots-cosx-10-sinx-1-sinx-2?rq=1